# Stack Too Deep Compiling Error on Remix -- Solidity

Tags: solidity

first off I’d like to say that I’m a noob in Solidity so this issue might sound so trivial, pls bear with me. I’m running into a compiler error on line 61 (Stack too deep). I suppose an easy fix would be to break blocks #2 and #3 into smaller functions but still be able to return the results on #4 for the parent function (#1). Basically, I’m would like to call the ‘buy’ function and then return #4 while breaking blocks #2 and #3 into smaller functions as a workaround “Stack too deep” error. How do I achieve this? Any help would be appreciated.

```
// Main function  (#1)
    function buy(address baseToken, address token, address exchangeRouterAddress) public payable returns (uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256, uint256) {
        uint256[] memory gas = new uint256[](2);

        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(exchangeRouterAddress);

        IERC20 _token = IERC20(token);
        IERC20 _baseToken = IERC20(baseToken);
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);

        if(baseToken != exchangeRouter.WETH()) {
            path[0] = exchangeRouter.WETH();
            path[1] = baseToken;
            exchangeRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{value: msg.value}(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        }
        else {
            IWETH(baseToken).deposit{value: msg.value}();
        }
        uint256 amount = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));
        
        // Nest function 1    (#2)
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = baseToken;
        path[1] = token;
        uint256 expToken = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(amount, path)[1];
        _baseToken.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        uint256 startGas = gasleft();
        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(amount, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        gas[0] = startGas - gasleft();
        uint256 rcvdToken = _token.balanceOf(address(this));

        // Nest function 2    (#3)
        path = new address[](2);
        path[0] = token;
        path[1] = baseToken;
        uint256 expBaseToken = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(rcvdToken, path)[1];
        _token.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        startGas = gasleft();
        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(rcvdToken, 0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        gas[1] = startGas - gasleft();
        uint256 rcvdBaseToken = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));

        // Finally return all results at once    (#4)
        return (expToken, rcvdToken, gas[0], expBaseToken, rcvdBaseToken, gas[1]);
    }
```

[image: Remix screenshot]

Comment: Can you add all your smart contract code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

using some tricks from https://soliditydeveloper.com/stacktoodeep, I'm able to compile your contract without the `stack too deep` error.

Here is an updated version, please note I didn't try to run it.

```
contract ReBuy {
    struct ExchangeResult {
        uint256 expected;
        uint256 received;
        uint256 gas;
    }

    function deposit(address token, address exchangeRouterAddress) internal {
        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            exchangeRouterAddress
        );
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);

        if (token != exchangeRouter.WETH()) {
            path[0] = exchangeRouter.WETH();
            path[1] = token;
            exchangeRouter.swapExactETHForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens{
                value: msg.value
            }(0, path, address(this), block.timestamp + 20);
        } else {
            IWETH(token).deposit{value: msg.value}();
        }
    }

    function exchangeToken(
        address fromToken,
        address toToken,
        address exchangeRouterAddress,
        uint256 amount
    )
        private
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        IUniswapV2Router02 exchangeRouter = IUniswapV2Router02(
            exchangeRouterAddress
        );
        uint256 expected;
        uint256 received;
        uint256 gas;
        address[] memory path = new address[](2);
        IERC20 token = IERC20(fromToken);
        path[0] = fromToken;
        path[1] = toToken;
        expected = exchangeRouter.getAmountsOut(amount, path)[1];
        token.approve(exchangeRouterAddress, type(uint256).max);
        gas = gasleft();
        exchangeRouter.swapExactTokensForTokensSupportingFeeOnTransferTokens(
            amount,
            0,
            path,
            address(this),
            block.timestamp + 20
        );
        gas = gas - gasleft();
        token = IERC20(toToken);
        received = token.balanceOf(address(this));
        return (expected, received, gas);
    }

    function buy(
        address baseToken,
        address token,
        address exchangeRouterAddress
    )
        public
        payable
        returns (
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256,
            uint256
        )
    {
        IERC20 _baseToken = IERC20(baseToken);
        uint256 amount;
        ExchangeResult memory tokenRes;
        ExchangeResult memory baseTokenRes;

        deposit(baseToken, exchangeRouterAddress);
        amount = _baseToken.balanceOf(address(this));

        (tokenRes.expected, tokenRes.received, tokenRes.gas) = exchangeToken(
            baseToken,
            token,
            exchangeRouterAddress,
            amount
        );

        (
            baseTokenRes.expected,
            baseTokenRes.received,
            baseTokenRes.gas
        ) = exchangeToken(
            token,
            baseToken,
            exchangeRouterAddress,
            tokenRes.received
        );

        // Finally return all results at once    (#4)
        return (
            tokenRes.expected,
            tokenRes.received,
            tokenRes.gas,
            baseTokenRes.expected,
            baseTokenRes.received,
            baseTokenRes.gas
        );
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Patrice! This was very helpful. However, I'm running into this error while trying to deploy on BSC testnet. I have 3.9 BNB so I'm not sure what's going on. 
```Gas estimation errored with the following message (see below). The transaction execution will likely fail. Do you want to force sending?
Internal JSON-RPC error. { "code": -32000, "message": "execution reverted" }
``` Any ideas?

Comment: I don't know about your issue, using brownie I can deploy this contract on BSC testnet: https://testnet.bscscan.com/address/0x26276A42D54b8047f880C9E2B2155Ba44E543580#code

Comment: I had 5 in the VALUE field for gas. Turns out BSC testnet does not accept gas to deploy. Changed it to 0 and it deployed. However, I haven't been successful calling the buy function (renamed to simulate_txn in the post). Could you pls take a peak? [link](https://ethereum.stackexchange.com/questions/124541/web3-exceptions-contractlogicerror-execution-reverted-pancakelibrary-insuffic)